# Equivalent Regex Unsupported lookbehind assertion IOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, regex, lookbehind

This regex:

```
var text = "Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't."
// break string up in to sentences based on punctation and quotation marks
var tokens = text.match(/(?<=\s+|^)[\"\'\‘\“\'\"\[\(\{\⟨](.*?[.?!])(\s[.?!])*[\"\'\’\”\'\"\]\)\}\⟩](?=\s+|$)|(?<=\s+|^)\S(.*?[.?!])(\s[.?!])*(?=\s+|$)/g);
```

breaks on IOS Safari due to unsupported `lookbehind assertions ((?<= ) and (?<! ))`. Is there an equivalent (or similar) regex for sentence tokenization that I can use? Preferably it should not break due to other iOS safari compatibility issues as referenced here: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#assertions)
ECMAScript (ECMA-262)
The definition of 'RegExp' in that specification.

Comment: Instead of links, please post your regex and samples in question

Comment: @anubhava Sure!

Comment: It can be any paragraph string with one or more sentences, I'll post an example regardless.

Comment: Can you try this regex in Safari: `/(?:\s|^)(?:["'‘“'"\[({⟨].*?[.?!](?:\s[.?!])*["'’”'"\])}⟩]|\S.*?[.?!](?:\s[.?!])*)(?=\s|$)/gm`

Comment: @Moderators that closed this question, it is not a duplicate it is just related by category. What I'm asking is quite specific that other post does not have the answer for it.

Comment: Yes I agree with point raised by @Ariel and reopened this question so that others can also try to post answers below

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your regex that you can use without using any lookbehind assertions to break input into sentences:

```
/(?:\s|^)(?:["'‘“'"\[({⟨].*?[.?!](?:\s[.?!])*["'’”'"\])}⟩]|\S.*?[.?!](?:\s[.?!])*)(?=\s|$)/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FP67AU/1)

Please keep in mind that your regex may break on sentences where there are words ending with dots such as `Jr., Sr. Mr.` etc and few more cases like that.

Comment: Not bad, but I added another example text that is better for this. Can you add support for Mr. Mrs. Jr.?

Comment: As I said, your original regex itself doesn't work with `Mr.`, `Sr.` etc and unfortunately there is no robust solution without lookbehind.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll look for something a bit more robust then.

Answer (score -1):

the issue was in `?<=`. if you somehow replace them, in my case `?!`, it might be fine.

Comment: Those are two different things. One is a positive lookbehind, the other a negative lookahead